# EmberJS global websocket connection

Tags: node.js, ember.js, socket.io, ember-data

Im using EmberJS and im trying to get data from the backend using websocket (socket.io) so i've set this Application Route

```
  App.ApplicationRoute = Ember.Route.extend(
  setupController: (controller, data) ->
    store  = @get 'store'
    socket = io.connect "http://localhost:4000/orders" ## Line 4
    socket.on "new_order", (order) ->
      store.load(App.Order, order)
    socket.on "new_billing", (bill) ->
      store.load(App.Bill, bill)
    socket.on "connected", ->
      console.log "Ready"
  model: ->
    return { title: "Ordenes" }
  actions:
    markAsDone: (type, type_id) ->
      # Send value to backend
      socket.emit "confirm_" + type,                    ## Line 16
        id: type_id
      # Find record by id
      if type == "order"
        record = App.Order.find(type_id)
        transition = "orders"
      else if type == "bill"
        record = App.Bill.find(type_id)
        transition = "bills"
      # Delete from store
      record.then( (r) ->
        r.deleteRecord()
      )
      # Display list of record type
      @transitionTo(transition)
)
```

on line 4 the connection is being set and object are being fetched when i hit "/", but after i enter a route "/orders" object are not being fetched anymore, and on line 16 in the code above, i cant use the socket variable

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: socket is not defined
```

Is there a better way to manage this ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

so the correct way to use a reusable socket is setting it inside the Store

```
App.Store = DS.Store.extend(
  revision: 12
  adapter: adapter
  socket: io.connect "http://localhost:4000/orders"
)
```

so then i can access to it inside any part of the code using

```
socket = @get 'store.socket'
```

Answer (score 1):

socket is out of scope once you've hit the markAsDone method, you can set a reference to it on the controller and retrieve it later (pardon my botched coffeescript)

```
  App.ApplicationRoute = Ember.Route.extend(
  setupController: (controller, data) ->
    store  = @get 'store'
    socket = io.connect "http://localhost:4000/orders" ## Line 4
    ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////// 
    controller.set 'socket', socket
    socket.on "new_order", (order) ->
      store.load(App.Order, order)
    socket.on "new_billing", (bill) ->
      store.load(App.Bill, bill)
    socket.on "connected", ->
      console.log "Ready"
  model: ->
    return { title: "Ordenes" }
  actions:
    markAsDone: (type, type_id) ->
      ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
      ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
      socket = @get 'controller.socket'
      # Send value to backend
      socket.emit "confirm_" + type,                    ## Line 16
        id: type_id
      # Find record by id
      if type == "order"
        record = App.Order.find(type_id)
        transition = "orders"
      else if type == "bill"
        record = App.Bill.find(type_id)
        transition = "bills"
      # Delete from store
      record.then( (r) ->
        r.deleteRecord()
      )
      # Display list of record type
      @transitionTo(transition)
)
```

Comment: doesnt seems to work
Assertion failed: Cannot delegate set('socket', {socket: [object Object], name: /orders, flags: [object Object], json: [object Object], ackPackets: 0, acks: [object Object], $events: [object Object]}) to the 'content' property of object proxy (generated application controller): its 'content' is undefined.

Uncaught Error: Object in path socke could not be found or was destroyed.

Anyways, will that fix the problem with socket not fetching new data when the route is diferent than root?

Comment: Yeah, you could totally store in on the app object itself.  It's just a namespaced variable.