# websockets with ember js

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I'm having some difficulty figuring out how to integrate websockets with my ember js app.  I don't know how to emulate websocket behavior in jsbin, so here's the nonfunctional example --

http://jsbin.com/iFUZoza/1/edit

Imagine this working up to the point where I log "finding..."  (It does.  I get the object I'm looking for from the socket.)  Unfortunately from there, I'm not sure how to get the contact model in question out of Ember.  Basically, I've listed all of the contacts in the UI, and I want to retrieve a single model from the controller and update it in real time.  I've got as far as getting the sockets functional, but I don't know how to get that model back.  I'm not even sure if I've inserted the socket code at the right place to do this.  Can someone help or point me in the right direction?

Thanks.

Comment: This post seems to have some information http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19896508/emberjs-global-websocket-connection but I can't find anything like a socket property in the ember-data API.  There's also a reference to socket support for Ember models here http://emberjs.com/guides/models/ but I can't find anything in the ember-data code or api specific to using sockets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the route its a good place to create the socket connection and the controllers are the place to react according to what happened in the socket.

I'd do something that resembles this JSBin:
http://jsbin.com/iFUZoza/4/edit?js,output

Hope this helps you!